# Javascript new Date() outputs 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' data as UTC although it's not

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, fullcalendar

I have a simple line of code which I need for a date output in a modal, that emerges when you click on an entry in my fullcalendar-script calendar. 
It looks like this:

```
 eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalStart').html(new Date(calEvent.start)); 
            $('#modalEnd').html(new Date(calEvent.end));
},
```

The JSON data that gets interpreted (`start` and `end`) is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s` and i want it to stay like that. But the modal with `new Date` outputs the following:

Start: Tue Aug 02 2016 **06**:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

End: Mon Aug 15 2016 **08**:00:01 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

although it should be

Start: Tue Aug 02 2016 **04**:00:00

End: Mon Aug 15 2016 **06**:00:01

I'm sure there is a simple solutio for this. I tried `.html(new Date(date.UTC()))` but that didn't work. I'd be very thankful if someone could help.

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @Andreas I really do not want to add any more scripts.. I'd like to just hardcode the format :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're planning to do, this should do the trick:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalStart').html(new Date(calEvent.start).toUTCString()); 
            $('#modalEnd').html(new Date(calEvent.end).toUTCString());
},
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much!! I'll accept this as an answer asap.